# How to dynamically change props of navigation screens in react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I wrote a `<Wizard>` and a `<Router>` component with react-navigation like so:

```
 generateNavigator = () => {
  const { steps, title, onSave, loggedIn } = this.props;
  const navigationRoutes = {};
  steps.forEach((step, index) => {
   const routeOptions = {
    screen: step.component,
    params: {
     bg: step.bg,
     text: step.text,
     image: step.image,
     onSave: onSave,
     loggedIn: loggedIn
    }
   };
   navigationRoutes[step.routeName] = routeOptions;
  });

  const navigationOptions = {
   headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
   },
   headerTintColor: '#111111',
   headerTitle: title,
  };

  const Stack = createStackNavigator(navigationRoutes, { navigationOptions });
  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(Stack);
  return AppContainer
 }
```

onSave is a function in the main App.js and loggedIn is a state from the main App.js (onSave is a function to change the bool-value of loggedIn)

The function works, but only `<Router>` and `<Wizard>` get the props update. The child-components form the navigation stack get only the initial value and won't update their props to the changed state from App.js

I tried this in my App.js onSave()-Function:

```
_onSave = (navigation) => {
    console.log(navigation);
    navigation.setParams({
      loggedIn:
        navigation.state.params.loggedIn === false ? true : false
    });
    this.state.loggedIn === false ? this.setState({ loggedIn: true }) : this.setState({ loggedIn: false });

}
```

This sets the param correctly, but if I go back from the screen or navigate further and navigate to the login screen again, the state is set back to false and I have to login again.

How can I save the "loggedIn" state for the screens of the navigation as well?

Currently there is no real login-logic, just a button-click as a clickdummy like this:

```
<Button
     style={styles.marginButton}
     onPress={() => {
      onSave(navigation);
     }}
>
```

Both `<Wizard>` and `<Router>` have the correct current state of loggedIn (false before buttonPress and true after buttonPress - even if I navigate). Just the params of the screen component just stay until I navigate away from the Login-Screen. After that it's set back to initial state.

I think the problem is, that once the Navigator is created the initial state stays as it is or maybe the navigation components don't rerender?...

I need a way to change and save the param even if I navigate to another screen.

Expo Snack: https://snack.expo.io/0RQU64li_

Comment: could you upload a codesandbox example?

Comment: updated the link again, sorry: https://snack.expo.io/0RQU64li_

Comment: `generateNavigator` is called in constructor, which means it runs once.
and that's where your props stop propagating

Comment: maybe try to follow https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

Comment: Where should I put generateNavigator() to update it's values from state-change?